# Emberjs hooks after ArrayController.addObjects is called EmberJs 1.0.0

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a route that uses a ArrayController to display objects. After certain actions the array gets populated again using the `controller.clear()` and `controller.addObjects()` method. I need to know when the news objects have been rendered so I can recalculate for some animation.

`didInsertElement` call back works when the the objects are rendered first time round but after `addObjects()` doesn't seem to trigger that it again.

How do I know when `addObjects()` have completed rendering?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might just observe the content of the controller and trigger then your recalculating function.

#### Pseudo example:

```
App.PostsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  recalculateStuff: function() {
    // do your recalculations here
  }.property('content.[]')
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: i think u meant .observe() instead of .property?